# How to remove section of string in pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

What I am looking to do is remove all text before the work 'of' in a string in a dataframe column. For example:

```
ColA          ColB 
 1       '12 miles ESE of Jackson,MS'
 2       '8 miles NE of New York, NY'
 3       '223 miles SW of Atlanta, GA'
```

What I am looking to get is this:

```
ColA           ColB 
 1           'Jackson,MS'
 2           'New York,NY'
 3           'Atlanta,GA'
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

You can do:

```
df['ColB'] = df['ColB'].str.split('of').str[1]
```

Answer (score 2):

Try, using regex and .str.extract:

```
"'" + df['ColB'].str.extract("of\s(.*$)")
```

Output:

```
                0
0    'Jackson,MS'
1  'New York, NY'
2   'Atlanta, GA'
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [.replace](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.replace.html):

```
df.ColB = df.ColB.replace(r'.*of (.*)', '\\1', regex=True)
```

then your ColB will be

```
    ColB
0   Jackson,MS
1   New York, NY
2   Atlanta, GA
```